# django circular import caused by Charfield default value

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model (Invitation, in models.py) with a variable inv calling a function (create_unique) that ensures a unique entry:

models.py

```
class Invitation(models.Model):
    inv = models.Charfield(unique=True, default=create_unique)

class OtherModel(models.Model):
    ...
```

the function create_unique is in invitations.py. Now the problem is, everytime I try to import Invitation, or another model from models.py in invitations.py, I get a circular import and I wonder how to solve it.

I only found two solutions to the problem:

# move create_unique outside invitations.py, but it really belongs there...
  # import the models inside invitations.py's functions, not a the beginnng of the file.

This solution is suboptimal, because the import may be needed outside the function (ie, for a signal receiver decorator).

invitations.py

```
from models.py import Invitation, OtherModel # this causes a circular import

def create_unique():
    unique = 'a unique string'
    return unique

def other_function():
    # this works but is redundant and limited to the function itself
    from models.py import Invitation, OtherModel
```

I've also tried, in the model, to specify the name of the function as a string (default='create_unique'), but this does obviously not work.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

full create_unique function:

```
def create_unique(length=30): 
    i=0 
    max = 100 
    while (i<max): 
        unique = u''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(length)) 
        try: 
            Invitation.objects.get(invite=unique) 
            return create_unique() 
        except Exception: 
            return unique
```

Comment: Can you specify a little what the funtion create_unique needs to actually do? I'm guessing the example is not really the full code, and while I can think of several ways to create unique strings I have no idea what you're going for, so I don't know if any of them are relevant

Comment: create_unique creates a unique string, calls Invitation to see if it is really unique or not and returns it (full code below). This function works, but the problem come from the circular import...       def create_unique(length=30): i=0 max = 100 while (i<max): unique = u''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(length))  try Invitation.objects.get(invite=unique) return create_unique() except return unique ... thank tou very much!

Comment: added the broken create_unique, check that is indented correctly. Can you please add to your OP all the imports you do in invitation and models? Also, the stacktrace would help figuring out what you're doing wrong. Python is not mistaken, you have a circular import somewhere. Also: `return create_unique()` returns a recursive call... are you sure your error isn't an infinite loop?

Comment: i do not know why, but the terminal does not print any stacktrace as usual, it just prints 'myconfig...$python manage.py test mymodule ImportError: cannot import name Invitation', no other information...